# How to configure SMTP setting on ubuntu NGINX server using PHP mailer library?

Tags: php, ubuntu, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

I want to configure SMTP Gmail relay on Ubuntu Nginx server via using PHPMailer library and email is successfully send when I run the script from my localhost but when I deploy its showing me these errors.

```
2020-12-04 11:27:10 SERVER -> CLIENT: 421 4.7.0 Try again later, closing connection.
2020-12-04 11:27:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO 1XX.1XX.9X.1XX
2020-12-04 11:27:10 SERVER -> CLIENT:
2020-12-04 11:27:10 SMTP ERROR: EHLO command failed:
2020-12-04 11:27:10 SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

I thought there is some port block of SMTP but I also tried to disable the firewall but still I am facing the same error. And here is my SMTP code.

```
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                  // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'XXXXXXX@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'XXXXXXXXX';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
    $mail->Port       = 587;                               // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for 
    $mail->setFrom('XXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('XXXXXXXX@gmail.com', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addReplyTo('XXXXXXXX@gmail.com', 'Joe');
```

but this code is working fine on a local machine and not is the live server.

Comment: That 421 error means that your server's IP is being throttled by google, probably because of spam originating from either your server or others in the same netblock as you. What does it say before that 421 error? Does your reverse DNS entry for your server's IP match your EHLO name?

Comment: It's showing the same error. Yes my server IP is match with EHLO IP. How can I fix it ?

Comment: It's not the IPs that need to match, it's the names: If you do a `dig a yourhost.example.com`, it will give you an IP; if you then `host <ip>`, it should give you back the name you started with. While this is a problem with your server, PHPMailer is not handling it correctly eitehr, which I will look at [on GitHub](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/2211).

Comment: I simply deploy on a server root folder for testing purpose, All the thing working fine on my local machine but not on a server, Is there any configuration required of SMTP, SSL and TLS because It's a fresh server.

you can also hit on this link to check the error http://168.119.98.191/mail/

Comment: Your code and settings are fine, but your local machine and server are on different networks, and google doesn't treat them the same, which is where your problem is coming from. I have pushed a fix in the master branch of PHPMailer that will handle this connection error better, but PHPMailer can't do anything to fix your network or the way that Google treats you.

Comment: I don't think the server setting are fine because I also run this script to another server and it's working fine on another server.

Comment: Ah, there is one thing – you should be using a name, not an IP for your envelope sender. That `EHLO` command should include your hostname, not your IP. If PHPMailer can't figure it out automatically, you can set it yourself using `$mail->Hostname = 'yourhostname.example.com';`

Comment: Right, and that other server will have a different IP that google can also treat differently.